# What does it mean to keep $inject in sync?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm reading [the Angular docs about injecting dependencies](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di), and am trying to figure what 'in sync' means.

As in, **what's the difference between keeping things 'in sync' vs keeping things 'in the same order'**?  The docs seem to imply that there's some difference between them.

## Context:

About **inline array notation**,

*When using this type of annotation, take care to keep the annotation array in sync with the parameters in the function declaration.*

About **`$inject` property annotation**,

*In this scenario the ordering of the values in the `$inject` array must match the ordering of the parameters in MyController.*

*Just like with the array annotation, you'll need to take care to keep the `$inject` in sync with the parameters in the function declaration.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'In sync' and 'in order' mean the same thing in this case.

The order is important in all cases apart from `Implicit Annotation` *(however an implicitly defined function will break during minification/uglification)*

As can be seen here:

```
app = angular.module('myApp', []);
// Inline Array Notation where we are defining the dependencies in the opposite order of what the function is defined as
app.controller('myInlineCtrl', ['$http', '$scope', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.testVal = '$scope passed as $scope';
    $http.testVal = '$http passed as $scope';
    // results in `$http passed as $scope`
}]);

// $inject Property Annotation
var myInjectorCtrl = function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.testVal = '$scope passed as $scope';
    $http.testVal = '$http passed as $scope';
    // results in `$http passed as $scope`
}
// Inject the dependencies in the opposite order
myInjectorCtrl.$inject = ['$http', '$scope'];
app.controller('MyInjectorCtrl', myInjectorCtrl);
```

The above test demonstrates that we are bound to the order of injection rather than the order of the arguments in the function definition.  This is consistent with being able to define a function with whichever argument names you wish (within reason) such that when it comes around to `minification` of the app, the function itself can get compressed but is still called with the correct arguments.

An example of that is this:

```
// Define a controller with your own argument names
app.controller('myMickeyMouseCtrl', ['$http', '$scope', '$timeout', function (mickey, donald, daffy) {
    mickey.testVal = 'mickey passed as $scope';
    donald.testVal = 'donald passed as $scope';
    daffy.testVal = 'daffy passed as $scope';
    // results in `donald passed as $scope`
}]);
```

Demo of all three http://jsfiddle.net/6qh2oyu6/

It's important to note also that if you define `myInjectorCtrl.$inject = ['$timeout'];` subsequently to already defining it you will clear the injections stored for that Controller function and in this case it would result with only the angular `$timeout` function being injected.

Comment: Right, so order is important.  I got that.  What does 'in sync' mean, as opposed to 'in order'?

Comment: I think you're reading too much into that.  I think in this case the two expressions are very much intended to mean the same.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for the answer!